# Magento 1.9 404 page showing after changing URL for products

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

I've edited some urls for products / categories. I've empty the DB table core_url_rewrite, I've reindexed all pages in admin, I've cleaned caches. But the products link on frontpage still showing 404 page not found. What did i miss?

Answer (score 0):

In order to deal with such issue, you need to go to phpMyAdmin and run following command. Please take database backup before run this command:

INSERT INTO

```
`report_event_types` (`event_type_id`, `event_name`, `customer_login`) VALUES
(1, 'catalog_product_view', 1),
(2, 'sendfriend_product', 1),
(3, 'catalog_product_compare_add_product', 1),
(4, 'checkout_cart_add_product', 1),
(5, 'wishlist_add_product', 1),
(6, 'wishlist_share', 1);
```